# F1 help in XBAP

Tags: .net, vmware, virtual-machine, xbap

I understand Stack Overflow is the place for really specific questions that only a couple of people would be interested in so here goes...

I have an application which is deployed as an XBAP which contains some embedded WinForms popup modal dialogs - it's a combination of legacy code and some new stuff and we don't have time for a complete re-write.

We've got context-sensitive help throughout which all works fine with one exception. If the user is running on a virtual machine and hits F1 in one of the modal popups then the help keyword doesn't get passed to the help handler, which means they get the top level help topic instead of the correct context sensitive stuff.

Told you it was really specific. Anybody got any ideas for why this is happening and how to fix/workaround the problem?

Thanks,
John